# Parse JSON String By Comma Deliminator Flutter

Tags: json, parsing, flutter, dart

I have some string that I need to separate into Latitude and Longitude to get LatLng but, do not know how to separate by delimiter to pull it off.

The string is: `{location: 40.748817,-73.985428}`

I need to separate it into Lat and lng to create a marker and do not know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this !

```
//If String
    String location = 'location: 40.748817,-73.985428';
     List<String> latAndLong =
        location.replaceFirst(' ', '').replaceAll('location:', '').split(',');
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(double.parse(latAndLong[0]),double.parse(latAndLong[1]));

    //If Map/JSON
    var location2 = {'location': '40.748817,-73.985428'};
    String locationExtracted = location2['location'].toString();
    List<String> latAndLong2 =
        locationExtracted.replaceFirst(' ', '').replaceAll('location:', '').split(',');
    LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(double.parse(latAndLong2[0]),double.parse(latAndLong2[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the actual input format is, it can be easier or harder.

If the input is actually a JSON map with the format `{"location": "40.748817,-73.985428"}`, then just parse it as JSON first, then split the string on the comma:

```dart
List<double> parseCoordinates(String source) {
  var parts = jsonParse(source)["location"]?.split(",");
  if (parts == null || parts.length != 2) {
    throw FormatException("Not valid location coordinates", source);
  }
  return [double.parse(parts[0], double.parts[1])];
}
```

If the input is actually a string of the form `{location: 40.748817,-73.985428}`, which is not valid JSON, then it looks like something which is actually most easily solved with a RegExp.

Example:

```dart
final _coordRE = RegExp(r"^\{location: (-?\d+(?:.\d+)), (-?\d+(?:.\d+))\}$");
List<double> parseCoordinates2(String source) {
  var match = _coordRE.firstMatch(source);
  if (match == null) throw FormatException("Not valid coordinates", source);
  return [double.parse(match[1]), double.parse(match[2])];
}
```

and then use it as

```dart
var coords = parseCoordinates(source);
var lat = coords[0];
var lng = coords[1];
```

Alternatively, since you know the format so precisely, you can just extract the substrings yourself instead of using a RegExp:

```dart
List<double> parseCoordinates(String source) {
  var prefix = "{location: ";
  if (source.startsWith(prefix) && source.endsWith("}")) {
    var commaIndex = source.indexOf(",", prefix.length);
    if (commaIndex >= 0) {
      var lat = double.parse(source.substring(prefix.length, commaIndex));
      var lng = double.parse(source.substring(commaIndex + 1, source.length - 1));
      return [lat, lng];
    }
  }
  throw FormatException("Not valid coordinates", source);
}
```

If the format can vary more than your example (perhaps it allows `-.5` as a coordinate, with no leading `0`), you'll have to adapt the regexp. One option is to have the capture groups simply capture `[-.\d]+` and rely on the double parser to handle syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function `jsonDecode`? It returns a dynamic.

```
var coordinate = jsonDecode('[your json string]');

print(coordinate['location']);
```

Then the rest is just to split it into tokens with `split()` function.
G'luck.